# Return more than one row when using MAX SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, max, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I HAVE 2 TABLES IN MS SQL:

table: Candidate
`CandidateId |PositionId`
`1              1`
`2              1`
`3              1`
`4              2`
`5              2`
`6              2`

table: Voting
`CandidateId |VoteCount`
`1              8`
`2              8`
`3              4`
`4              7`
`5              6`
`6              7`

AND I WANT TO RETURN A TABLE LIKE THIS
(returning the List of Candidates with Max VoteCount)

`CandidateId |PositionId |VoteCount`
`1              1              8`
`2              1              8`
`4              2              7`
`6              2              7`

In case that more than one row have same MAX Vote Count it will show the 2 rows instead. I tried it many times but it always returns one row.
Can you help me, what query can i use?

Comment: Why dont you use ORDER BY VoteCount Desc for this?

Comment: Why aren't IDs 3 and 5 getting returned?  Because they only have one record each?

Comment: You haven't even mentioned by what column(s) you want to group.

Comment: Is this `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: What MAX number? There is nothing in your expected output that indicates any kind of aggregation at all. Some explanation of what you actually want is required if you want help.

Comment: i want to get the maximum votecount per PositionId...so in case there are the SAME MAX vote counts, it will return more than one rows....i tried MAX() but it returns only one row

Comment: Basically all you want is the `TOP` 2 vote counts per `PositionId` correct?

Comment: i want to return the max vote count ,group by positionid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does not uses dense_rank(), should works on MySQL also

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   yourtable t
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT PositionId, max(VoteCount) as VoteCount
  FROM   yourtable
  GROUP BY PositionId
) m    ON t.PositionId = m.PositionId
       AND t.VoteCount = m.VoteCount
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
   SELECT *, dense_rank() over (partition by PositionId order by VoteCount desc) as rn
   FROM   yourtable
 ) d WHERE  d.rn = 1
```